# Firebase Hosting Issue Deploying Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to get my flutter website hosted from Firebase, the problem is that it seems like not all the files are being published.

Firebase shows only 4 files deployed but there should be a lot more.

I tried `firebase init` then selected only hosting, selected my firebase project, used public as public directory, and did not rewrite URLs to index.html

This is what I'm seeing when I navigate to my website, what did I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you ran `flutter build web` and `firebase deploy --only hosting`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai yessir!

Comment: @PeterKoltai it now looks like 12 files have been deployed (still many more to go) and the web is just a blank page

Comment: Can you run in debug mode locally from Chrome?

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes that works as expected, web app loads and is functional

Comment: After `flutter build web`, the build files will be within your project's root, under `build/web`. So you need to set the `"public": "build/web",` in `firebase.json`.

Comment: @PeterKoltai it looks like it is working now, but 1 thing is not - routing. Navigating to a link like www.mywebsite.com/certainPage isn't going to that certain page anymore, just a 404 error page

Comment: Good news. Have you added `www.domain.com` as well, not only `domain.com`?. You can set up a redirect in Firebase Console.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yup! www.domain.com points to domain.com